# Safe read-only sqlite3 database

Tags: security, sqlite

I want to give my website users arbitrary read-only access to an
SQLite3 database, without letting them write to the database or do any
other damage. How?

Making the db file read-only helps a little, but commands like
"ATTACH", ".load" and ".output" allow people to read/write other
files, which may not be protected.

Of course, if I knew all such commands, I'd just filter against them,
but I'm mostly worried about commands I haven't thought of.

I tried briefly to alter sqlite3's source code to disallow writes, but
this is harder than it looks: even the SELECT statement appears to do
some internal INSERTS/etc.

**Note :** *I've considered DOS attacks, and will ulimit cputime to 5s or
something. My main concern is damage to files/"hacking", not DOS.*

chroot() may work, but seems extreme.

Thoughts?

**EDIT :** Wow, did I really ask this 3+ years ago?

Since then, [I've actually written a program to do this.](https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/bc-run-sqlite3-query2.pl)

which I think is reasonably secure (but I could be wrong).

[Here is a sample query.](http://4c6747383f0418dce674932beeefbf87.metarnew.db.bcinfo3.barrycarter.info/)

Comment: I guess I'm really looking for a "meta-solution" here. For example, if I ran my entire system off a read-only CD, I wouldn't have to worry about what sqlite3 can/can't do. That's too extreme in my case, but the general idea is I want to find a solution that works w/o depending on sqlite3 properties.

Answer (score 1):

> Of course, if I knew all such
>   commands, I'd just filter against
>   them, but I'm mostly worried about
>   commands I haven't thought of.

Have you considered using a whitelist instead of a blacklist?  Only allow statements that start with SELECT or EXPLAIN.

Comment: Yes, but *you* don't have to allow it.  Instead of sqlite3_exec, use prepared statements, which execute only one statement at a time.

Comment: A user writing queries is the exact opposite of prepared statements.

Comment: I think I'm OK w/o multiple queries in one go, but I'm still worried about nested queries. However, if the file's read-only, that may be OK. I'll check if SQLite3 responds to "SELECT * FROM (ATTACH ...)" type queries.

I'm also worried about (for example) semicolons that'll make sqlite run multiple queries anyway. Of course, I can filter against semicolons, but you get the general idea.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned how you are providing access to the SQLite database.

If you are doing so through the C API (e.g. writing a CGI in C that takes a raw SQL query, passes it to sqlite, and then returns whatever was returned), then the dot commands like ".load" are of no concern.  These are implemented by the [sqlite3 shell program](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html), and will not work when calling the C API functions directly.

In this case you can call [sqlite3_open_v2](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_open) passing SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY as one of the flags to prevent the database from being written.

The ATTACH command can be disabled by calling sqlite3_limit() to set SQLITE_LIMIT_ATTACHED to 1 to prevent attaching a second database from succeeding.  Since the [DETACH](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_detach.html) statement "detaches an additional database connection previously attached using the ATTACH statement" it sounds like this would prevent one from detaching the original database in order to bypass this restriction.

As far as I can tell from looking at the [SQL understood by SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang.html), this should close up all the holes.  You may wish to run through the [pragmas](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html) with a fine-tooth comb just to make sure, if there is anything I missed let me know and I'll update this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assure that your user has write access and that other users (especially the user that the webserver runs as) has only read access to the file itself.  How you do this of course depends on your platform (Linux, Windows, etc.)

Comment: Right. That part's easy. The hard part: what sqlite3 commands can access other files (eg, ATTACH).

Answer (score 0):

Make your database file read only in the operating system. Once you've done that SQLite can't override it. If you still have issues it's not a SQLite issue. They might still be able to find a php/cgi/etc issue but that's the nature of the security beast.

Comment: Unfortunately, not true (that was my original plan). Commands like ATTACH can access other files.

Comment: If your environment doesn't allow access to other files there's not a lot they can do with it. Can you run it in a chroot jail?